# How does ViewPager work as a ViewGroup/Container

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-viewpager

From the first day i have started to learn Android, i find the xml issue as the most hard thing for me to understand.
I see that **ViewPager** extend *ViewGroup* and my issues are:

1. Why **ViewPager** xml attributes (like background) aren't displayed in it's class explanation [Android Site: ViewPageer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager): 
   How can i know which attributes are supported with **ViewPager** ?
2. **ViewPager** as a container. It's is written that **ViewPager.LayoutParams** extends **ViewGroup.LayoutParams** but in the following link: [Android Site : ViewPager.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.LayoutParams) it's is written that **ViewGroup.LayoutParams** inherits the field *height* and *width* without saying nothing about *layout_width* and *layout_height**. Is it only a lack in Android documentation or i'm missing something?
   Is it ok to define *layout_height* and *layout_width* in xml file that will be added to **ViewGroup** (via *PageAdapter*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Raise a documentation bug as it seems that some documentation pages list the XML attributes and the inherited ones and some don't.

My guess is because ViewPager does not have an specific xml attributes I think then nothing is listed including all the inherited ones. If you want to see all the xml attributes, click on the parent classes (background is inherited from the `view` class)

2) Again mostly because it mostly inherited from parent classes.

Really while ViewPager is a type of ViewGroup container it is really designed as shortcut container of Fragments therefore the documentation focuses on how to work with that.

Comment: Thank you.. i will send them